# Why does android not have a function for putting a String value into a JSONObject?

Tags: android, json

I see a lot of examples like this on the internet:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("name", "myname");
```

How can people have been giving examples like this when the JSONObject doesn't have put(String name, String value) function. At least it's missing from any documentation I can find plus my Android studio fires up all in red if I even start trying to put string value into the object.

Can someone please explain to me why a function for putting strings into JSONobject as values is missing from android?

Thanks for the information in advance

Comment: Because that was how the API was defined. The method *could* have been overloaded with only specialized types, but it wasn't - which does allow (and accept) slop from the caller. Note that String is a sub-type of Object and can thus be passed so. (Internally `theObject.ToString` or equivalent is called as appropriate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this link http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
JSONObject  put(String name, Object value)
Maps name to value, clobbering any existing name/value mapping with the same name.
```

Datatype Object is the root class of the Java class hierarchy. All non-primitive types (including arrays) inherit either directly or indirectly from this class.

Therefore jsonObject.put("name", "myname");  is a valid statement.

Answer (score 0):

At least there is a documented method to this issue [put(String name, Object value)](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)). You just have to handle a JSONException.

Comment: Thank you for the exception point. For some reason I haven't seen that in any of the examples and since I couldn't compile the code I had no idea it could be solved like this.